# Force textarea to merge into three <td>

Tags: html, css

Currently messing around and have created a form which is being positioned within a table.

I have three columns in my table and two rows.

The top row contains three input elements as you can tell by the picture, and on the second row i have a textarea. The problem i'm having is that i'm trying to change the textarea to a width which matches the three input areas above, but when i try to extend the width, obviously it is forcing the input elements further across as it is in a table.

Can someone tell me a way i can somehow merge the bottom row to allow me to stretch my textarea.

https://dumpyourphoto.com/photo/xIwlb9oqYQ#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd row should look like this.

```
<tr><td colspan="3"><textarea></textarea></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You merge the table cells.
Instead of:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

You have to write:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="3">
    <textarea></textarea>
  </td>
</tr>
```